# ASP.NET VB.NET Search button on masterpage doesn't navigate to the correct directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a search input and button in a masterpage that I would like to redirect to the same directory that the user is currently in. If user is in myurl.com/Manage/default.aspx, i would like the redirect to be myurl.com/Manage/search.aspx. If the user is in myurl.com/Field/default.aspx, I would like the redirect to be myurl.com/Field/search.aspx.

I can only get it to redirect to one directory or the other.

I have tried HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, and several other HttpContext ideas that do not work to get the current folder directory a user is in.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Manage/search.aspx?searchstring=" + qSearch.Text)
or
Response.Redirect("~/Field/search.aspx?searchstring=" + qSearch.Text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked with a master page, but I think it's easier than it seems. Since you always want the `search.aspx` page in the current directory, you don't have to specify the directory.

```
Response.Redirect("search.aspx?searchstring=" + qSearch.Text)
```

I think that should always go to the nearest search page.

Comment: I asked the wrong question. was up late last night. you're right you answered it correctly. what i really need to know is if user is in a totally different directory such as /Manage/Accounting/default.aspx, how do I redirect to /Manage/Search, while keeping the ability to get to there from all directories. i'll ask a different question on a different thread and mark your as answer, since you are right on what i asked?